# How to do inner join using only ID in Hibernate Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate

Assume I have this mapping:

```
class User {
    String name;
    ...
}
class Department {
    String id;
    User owner;
    ...
}
class Employee {
    String departmentId; //legacy code, I cannot change this
}
```

I want to query all `Employee`s sorted by their department owner's name (sorted by `Employee.departmentId.owner.name`) using Hibernate Criteria API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria api or hql works with relational mapping so you can not use something like departmentId.owner.name. But there are some solutions [here](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/hibernate_hql_inner_join_on_clause).

Comment: Thanks, the last solution is perfect , is it possible to do that using Criteria?

Comment: I think, it is impossible. You should consider using native query.